# What is it called when I can select a HTML element in JS using it's ID?

Tags: javascript, html

I've noticed that I can use `a` to reference an element with an ID of "a" but I'm not sure if there's a name for this "method".

For example this would set the div's text to "b c".

```
<div id="a" class="b c"></div>
<script>a.innerHTML = a.classList</script>
```

Comment: Not sure of the name, but here's some discussion about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables

Comment: [named access on the window object](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11691401/2643846)

Comment: in jQuery selecting-element based on class/id etc is called Selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be called [Named access on the Window object](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#named-access-on-the-window-object) by HTML5 standard. Read more [here](http://www.2ality.com/2012/08/ids-are-global.html)

> The window object must have a
>   property `key` whose value is `elem` if:
>
> - there is exactly one DOM element `elem` whose property `id` has the value `key`.
> - there is exactly one DOM element `elem` whose property `name` has the value `key`.  `elem`’s tag must be one of: a, applet, area, embed, form,
>     frame, frameset, iframe, img, object.